# Copying sheets to existing workbook, workbook name is cell.value

Tags: excel, vba

Very new here. Having a hard time trying to debug. I am currently trying to make the macro work as the following:

Create new sheets and rename it to cell. Value in range, and if there is a workbook (also named as the sale cell.Value) in the same folder as the macro, copy this sheet into the workbook; if not, create a new workbook, name it the cell.Value and copy the sheet into this new workbook.

I am have trouble with copying the sheet into the existing workbook part: I'm guessing it's the way I'm putting the workbook name?

```
Sub SplitandFilterSheet()

Sheet2.Activate

Dim Splitcode As Range

Set Splitcode = Range("Splitcode2")

'Use each cell in Splitcode to name each newly copied worksheet

For Each cell In Splitcode
Sheets("Realized").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value

'In each newly created worksheet, filter ParentID by the worksheet name (for example, 004), and then fill in color in those cells

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(CStr(cell.Value)).Range("MasterData2")
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=" & CStr(cell.Value), Operator:=xlFilterValues
.Offset(1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 5

'Unfilter

ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

'Now filter ParentID cells that do not have color (i.e. anything that is not 004, since rowsa where ParentID=004 has color) and then delete

.AutoFilter Field:=2, Operator:=xlFilterNoFill
.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

'Unfilter, make color as blank, and rename sheet with Realize or Unrealized

ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
.Offset(1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 0


Dim FilePath As String, wb As Workbook

    FilePath = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    FilePath = Dir("C:\Users\hsush001\Downloads\test\" & cell.Value & ".xlsx")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If FilePath = "" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\hsush001\Downloads\test\" & cell.Value & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Else
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\hsush001\Downloads\test\" & cell.Value & ".xlsx")
    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook
    Sheet(CStr(cell.Value)).Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    wb.Saved = True
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End With

Next cell
MsgBox "Macro Completed"

End Sub
```

This line: `Sheet(CStr(cell.Value)).Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)` keeps getting bugged out.. sometimes saying Subscript out of range, or object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: a) It should be `SheetS(CStr(cell.Value)).Copy` (you're missing an *s*) b) Your `For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook` is out of place and has no `Next`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheet(CStr(cell.Value)).Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
```

`Sheet` was assigned and iterated through ThisWorkbook as a single worksheet. You want to identify one of the worksheets in the ThisWorkbook.Worksheets collection¹ by name.

```
'bunch of code
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\hsush001\Downloads\test\" & cell.Value & ".xlsx")
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cell.Value).Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
'more code
```

The `For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook` serves no real purpose and is missing its `Next Sheet` to close the loop.

---

¹ <sub>I prefer to work within the Worksheets collection instead of the Sheets collection but you could use the latter; it is simply personal choice in this situation. However *after:=Sheets.Count* guarantees the end of the queue while *after:=WorksSheets.Count* only guarantees after the last worksheet.</sub>